# Creating a multi chart barplot in seaborn or matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe below,

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Signal1':[1.9, 2.5, 3.2, 4.3, 8.4, 7.8],
                         'Signal2':[4.7, 2.3, 7.8, 9.1, 7.2, 1.3],
                         'Labels':['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C']})


    Signal1 Signal2 Labels
0   1.9      4.7    A
1   2.5      2.3    A
2   3.2      7.8    B
3   4.3      9.1    B
4   8.4      7.2    C
5   7.8      1.3    C
```

Now I would like to create a bar plot such as like this,
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg3fg.jpg)

It'd be a great help if somebody shed some light on this problem.

 Thank you!

Comment: This is explained in the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html), for [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html), and for [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/grouped_barplot.html). It would be good to search for answers before asking a question on SO.

Comment: @Mr.T , I understand we can use the above code you mentioned. Please check the image, I want "Label" on X-AXIS.

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
data.plot(kind='bar')
```

output:

[image]

Comment: SO has the duplicate flag for a reason.

Comment: @Mr.T , I understand we can use the above code you mentioned. Please check the image, I want "Label" on X-AXIS.